# React useEffect if user is null. redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to make a protected route in next JS. I've added a use effect to redirect if no user to the sign-in page

```
  const analytics = () => {
  const { userLoaded, user, signOut, session, userDetails, subscription } =
    useUser();
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(session);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (!session) router.replace("/admindashboard");
    }, 3000);
  }, [session]);

  return (
    <>
      <Dashboard />
      <p>Coming soon</p>
    </>
  );
};
```

export default analytics;

the problem is I'm using a custom hook for supabase where I call the user. and when the page loads for some reason it's null then true for the user but because it's null it redirects when it doesn't need to I'm confused about how to prevent this

Context

```
import { useEffect, useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { supabase } from "../utils/supabaseClient";

export const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [userLoaded, setUserLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [session, setSession] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState(null);
  const [subscription, setSubscription] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const session = supabase.auth.session();
    setSession(session);
    setUser(session?.user ?? null);
    const { data: authListener } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(
      async (event, session) => {
        setSession(session);
        setUser(session?.user ?? null);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      authListener.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
  const updateAvatar = (url) =>
    supabase.auth.update({
      data: { avatar_url: url },
    });

  const updateCardFav = async (favId) =>
    await supabase.from("user_faved").insert([{ name: favId }]);

  const updateUserName = (userEnteredName) => {
    supabase.auth.update({
      data: { full_name: userEnteredName },
    });
  };
  const getUserDetails = () => supabase.from("users").select("*").single();
  const getSubscription = () =>
    supabase
      .from("subscriptions")
      .select("*, prices(*, products(*))")
      .in("status", ["trialing", "active"])
      .single();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      Promise.allSettled([getUserDetails(), getSubscription()]).then(
        (results) => {
          setUserDetails(results[0].value.data);
          setSubscription(results[1].value.data);
          setUserLoaded(true);
        }
      );
    }
  }, [user]);

  const value = {
    session,
    user,
    updateCardFav,
    userDetails,
    updateUserName,
    userLoaded,
    subscription,
    updateAvatar,
    signIn: (options) => supabase.auth.signIn(options),
    signUp: (options) => supabase.auth.signUp(options),
    signOut: () => {
      setUserDetails(null);
      setSubscription(null);
      return supabase.auth.signOut();
    },
  };
  return <UserContext.Provider value={value} {...props} />;
};

export const useUser = () => {
  const context = useContext(UserContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`useUser must be used within a UserContextProvider.`);
  }
  return context;
};
```

Comment: aren't you just looking for `if (!userLoaded && !user)` in this case or is that not what that variable represents?

Comment: @RandyCasburn hooks don't work that way, they all need to be called at the top level of a component

Answer (score 1):

You need simply to add isLoading to user then it is simple.

First value of isLoading needs to be true.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!isLoading && !user) {
    router.push("/admindashboard");
    return;
  }
  return;
}, [user, isLoading]);
```

in your hook

```js
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)
useEffect(() => {
  if (user) {
    Promise.allSettled([getUserDetails(), getSubscription()]).then(
      (results) => {
        setUserDetails(results[0].value.data);
        setSubscription(results[1].value.data);
        setUserLoaded(true);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    ).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      setLoading(false);
      setUserLoaded(false);
    });
  }
}, [user]);
```

Comment: my problem is userLoaded in my hook will return false if they is no user to be loaded I will share

Comment: @KeoooDev check out my edit

Comment: if I console log this I get
`true false 'Session'
newjob.js?0686:19 true null 'Session'`

Comment: https://vscode.dev/github/vercel/nextjs-subscription-payments

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (userLoaded && !user) {
      router.push("/admindashboard");
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }, [user, userLoaded]);
```

this should solve the issue.